# Decision Metrics for Selecting Promopt Structures: Creating a Prompt-Based System

Tags: prompt, huggingface, large-language-model

I am Newbie in this field
I'm currently working on developing a system that generates various prompts structures (such as tree of thoughts, chain of thoughts, etc.) in response to user prompts. However, I'm facing a challenge in determining the most suitable thought structure for a given prompt. in machine learning, metrics like accuracy, F1 score, precision, and recall aid in choosing the best model. Similarly, I'm exploring if there exist analogous metrics or approaches that can provide numerical guidance in selecting between different thought structures.

If anyone has insights into potential metrics, methodologies, or even analogous concepts from other fields that might help in objectively determining which thought structure (tree, chain, etc.) is best suited for a particular prompt, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Ex:-

User Prompt:- I Want To Learn About Elephent. In Output One Prompt Based On Chain Of Thoughts Other Is Based On Tree Of Thoughts Or Other Prompt Enginerrring Techniques

We Will Have Two Output How To Consider Which One Is Best?

Thank you for your time and expertise!"